# How to display values of "parameters" and "localparaters" in gtkwave iverilog simulation?

Tags: verilog, iverilog, gtkwave

Gtkwave is displaying all the registers and signal values in the simulation using iverilog, but I can not find a way to display the parameters and localparameter values. Any advice?

Comment: If the dump file does not contain these values, can you manually assign their values to wires?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iverilog VCD(**V**alue **C**hange **D**ump) currently only supports signals that change change values. This is being worked on as enhancement to masquerade parameters as signals at time 0.  https://github.com/steveicarus/iverilog/pull/714